# Reading message history facebook messenger

Tags: android, facebook, messenger

I'm building a machine learning android app that would analyze a user's typing style. My goal is to read all messages the user has sent using Facebook messenger. This includes every thread they have participated in. Is this possible using the Facebook api? I got a little confused while reading the documentation. Could you point me in the right direction on where to look or how to get started with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to access the user messages/inbox anymore, that possibility was removed a while ago: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/inbox

> This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v2.4.

Comment: On the top of the page it say: "This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v2.4"